RBF for time series
i want protect some time series.
I have some 2023 data on air pollutants, including PM2.5, SO2, and NO2 concentrations, as well as temperature data for that year. I used a single ARIMA model to predict December 1st to December 15th, using the data from July to November as the test set. I want to use an RBF (Radial Basis Function) to train the aforementioned data to optimize the prediction results. Is this feasible?

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

how to ask a good question:
how to ask
